# Возможно растянуть заголовки табов QTabWidget по ширине экрана?

Tags: c++, qt, tab

У меня есть QTabWidget, который отображаются так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Возможно растянуть заголовки QTabWidget-та, по ширине экрана, чтоб он подстраивался под размеры экрана?

Так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И если да , то как это сделать?
В коде у меня QTabWidget объявляется так :

```
   QTabWidget *MainTab;
...
    MainTab = new QTabWidget(this);
```

В UI интерфейсе verticalLayout добавляется, а таб потом добавляю следующим кодом:

```
ui->verticalLayout_Main->addWidget(MainTab);
```

Comment: ui->verticalLayout_Main->setSpacing(0); или ui->verticalLayout_Main->setMargins(0);

Comment: если в дизайнере делаете, то посмотрите в свойствах лэйаута параметры spacing и margins, насколько я помню они отвечают за размещение элементов

Comment: @goldstar_labs Это не помогло ui->verticalLayout_Main->setSpacing(0); А этого нет вообще setMargins(0); Мне надо растянуть заголовки табов, а не сам QTabWidget

Comment: @goldstar_labs  Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 3):

В документации [QTabBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html) есть интересная фраза:

> The following virtual functions may need to be reimplemented in order
> to tailor the look and feel or store extra data with each tab:

Из которой узнаем, что переопределение метода [QSize QTabBar::tabSizeHint(int index) const [virtual protected]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#tabSizeHint) позволит устанавливать ширину вкладок. Но метод `tabSizeHint` `protected`, поэтому нужно будет отнаследоваться от `QTabBar` и перекрыть метод `tabSizeHint`, устанавливая для вкладок нужную ширину.

`QTabBar`является частью [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html) и у того есть метод [void QTabWidget::setTabBar(QTabBar *tb) [protected]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabBar), но метод тоже `protected`, поэтому понадобится отнаследоваться от `QTabWidget` и, например, в конструкторе вызвать `setTabBar` и туда поместить наш модифицированный `QTabBar`

Comment: А автоматически будут заголовки подстраиваться по размеры главного окна Приложения?

Comment: Я многое понял из этого. Надо пробовать

Comment: Будут, если это будет написано в tabSizeHint. Т.е. нужно будет узнать ширину qtabbar, поделить на количество табов и вернуть эту ширину. Код вам предоставить не смогу, зато помогу с примерами: https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=tabSizeHint&type=Code :)